# Getting padding and margins inside parent's width

Tags: html, css

I have an elementary problem with my web that is driving me nuts.

Imagine that I have a container div which I set to be `max-width 1024 px`. Then I have two more divs inside it that are `width:50%` each of them. I try to add a `padding` to the insider divs, but then it overflows above the `1024 max-width` pixels of the container div.

My doubt is, if the `padding` are like inner-margins, they are part of the element, wouldn't it be supposed to be counted inside that 50% `width`? In other words, I want **the element + the `padding`** to be 50%, not just the element.

Just to make things clearer,

This is how it looks now :

[image]

... and this is how it should look. :

[image]

So, what should I do?

Comment: Screenshots without the actual code don't give enough information. Please provide us a demo at JsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or another way we can take a look at the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The box model it's like this:

`Total width = width + padding + border`

If you have got a 1000px of width + 10px of padding it will be a 1020px of total width.

To avoid this you can use this property:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Indeed and most CSS Resets will include this automatically.

Comment: I don't like reseters that make this kind of things, but for tastes we have the colours :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `box-sizing: border-box` to your inner `div`'s so the width given includes your padding.

If you intend to use margin, that will not do it.

For that you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), so if your inner `div`'s will have a 5px margin, it would look like this

```
width: calc(50% - 10px);
```

And you can combine them ...

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="inner">
  </div>

    <div class="inner">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual width something like ::

```
<div style="width:1024px">
    <div style="width:502px;padding:5px"></div>
    <div style="width:502px;padding:5px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks to @marcosperezgude you also have to consider your border width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the paddings are like inner-margins, they are part of the element's actual size.
You should calculate

**total element width = width + left padding + right padding + left border + right border + left margin + right margin**
e.g.

The two `<div>` elements above end up with different sizes in the result (because div2 has a padding specified).

```css
.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;    
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">This div is smaller (width is 300px and height is 100px).</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px).</div>
```

For your problem you will have to use `box-sizing: border-box;`
The CSS3 box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

If you set `box-sizing: border-box;` on an element padding and border are included in the width and height:

See below example

```css
.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;    
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Both divs are the same size now!</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">Hooray!</div>
```

Comment: You are wrong, the margins doesn't affect to the total width of an element (it affects to the render, but not to the total widht)